# How can you subset a SwiftyJSON JSON object

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am building an iOS app in which one of my API calls returns a large JSON blob that I load into a JSON object using SwiftyJSON. For example, it looks something like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "name":"object name",
    "id":1,
    "description":"short description of object",
    "type":"type",
    "runs":[
    ],    
}
```

As part of the app the user can modify things like the name, but the API endpoint for the PATCH call needs to have the `runs` key removed. Does anyone know how to take a SwiftyJSON JSON object and create a new one that has a subset of keys. For example, I want the JSON blob to look like

```
{
  "data": {
    "name":"object name",
    "id":1,
    "description":"short description of object",
    "type":"type"   
}
```

I have spent many hours trying various things with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do this: `json["data"]["runs"] = nil`

Comment: That does not completely remote the entry, rather results in the following. I need that whole entry removed so the tag doesn't show.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "name":"object name",
    "id":1,
    "description":"short description of object",
    "type":"type",
    "runs":null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the associated `dictionaryValue` from your SwiftyJSON object and use the `removeValueForKey` method.

Of course it means you have to assign the `dictionaryValue` to a variable, you can't remove a key in the SwiftyJSON object itself.

Example:

```
var dataDict = json["data"].dictionaryValue
dataDict.removeValueForKey("runs")
```

*Note: the `removeValueForKey` method name is a bit misleading; it will remove the key, not just the value.*

Comment: Thanks. How can I then stick the modified piece back into the original json blob? So given `var json = JSON(["data": {"name":"test", "runs":[]}")` at the end of the day I want to end up with is `"data": {"name":"test"}`. I get removing the `runs` piece, but it isn't clear what to do after that.

Comment: SwiftyJSON only decodes JSON to custom objects, you can't add a dictionary to a SwiftyJSON object. Also, you don't need to: the common way is to assign the values *from* the SwiftyJSON object to variables and use these variables in your app, not to use the SwiftyJSON object itself as a writable datastore (which it is not).

Comment: Thanks @eric-d. You got me pointed in the right direction and I was able to figure it out. I understand your point about not using SwiftyJSON object directly. Just for sake of anyone else who may want it though, what I ended up doing was `var newJSON = JSON(["data":JSON(dataDict)]).

Comment: Oh, nicely done! I forgot we could initialize an new SwiftyJSON object like that. You're welcome, enjoy, and congrats for this idea.