# swift SwiftyJSON cannot set object

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
var petArray: JSON!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var tmp: NSMutableArray!
    tmp = NSMutableArray()
    tmp.addObject(["name":"pet01", "age":15, "type":"dog", "breed":"QQ", "size":"small", "comment":"qqqq", "selected":0]);
    tmp.addObject(["name":"pet02", "age":15, "type":"dog", "breed":"QQ", "size":"small", "comment":"wwww", "selected":0]);

    petArray = JSON(tmp)

    petArray[0]["name"] = JSON("QQQQ") //why cannot update????

    print(petArray)
}
```

I tried to update the name at first index, but it's no use

If something wrong?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219237/how-can-you-subset-a-swiftyjson-json-object/32229511#32229511): OP in a comment to my answer explains how he actually did it. // In short: SwiftyJSON objects are immutable, you have to recreate them with new data or transform them in arrays/dictionaries before you can edit the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update it before convert to JSON.